# HTML Form not posting to PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms

I am currently creating an HTML form that has 2 fields; name and an address. It also has a way of selecting one of 2 options.  The form will either be used to look up the address of a person.  In this case, only the name field is required to be filled out.  The other option is to add a person to the file. In this case both fields need to be filled out. For some reason, I am not able to get the values that inputted from the form into my PHP file. Please help.

Here is my HTML Form

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Form </title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
<div>
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name"><br>
</div>
<div>
<label for=address">Address: </label>
<input id="address" type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="radio" name="action" value="lookup">Lookup<br>
<input type="radio" name="action" value="add">Add<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP file

```
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "<p>",$_POST["name"],"</p>";
echo "<p>",$_POST["action"],"</p>";
echo "<p>",$_POST["address"],"</p>";
$address = array();
if($_POST["action"]=="lookup"){
$fh = fopen("address.txt","r") or die("No such file found.");
while(!feof($fh)) {
   $line = fgets($fh);
   $info = explode("|",$line);
   $address[$info[0]]=$info[1];
   }
if(array_key_exists($_POST["name"],$address)) {
   echo "<p>",$_POST["name"],"<p>";
   echo "<p>",$address[$_POST["name"]],"</p>";

}

?>



<body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the directory structure. where these files are located?

Comment: Are both files are on the same working location (means in the same folder?)

Comment: u are working on localhost or any server

Comment: Also `echo "<p>",$_POST["name"],"</p>";` have errors. it should be `echo "<p>".$_POST["name"]."</p>";` and same for others

Comment: Also `if($_POST["action"]=="lookup")` is missing closing bracket

Comment: I am working on a Linux machine, and yes they are both in the same folder. Here is the location: computer/var/www/html & both files are in that html folder.

Comment: Thanks guys, it is now posting the info that is typed into my form, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in

`echo "<p>",$_POST["name"],"</p>";`

It should be

`echo "<p>".$_POST["name"]."</p>";`

and same for others